# Power Presets - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, power-management, suspend

Hello Ubuntu Community,

On Windows, I was able to set different power plans ("Never Off", "Charging", etc.) which allowed me to change suspend/screen turn off settings with the click of a button. However, I'm not sure exactly how to do this on Ubuntu.

Anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Power settings are available at

> System settings > Power option

where you can set suspend time, if you're on a laptop you can set lid events too. For turning off screen, look at system

> settings > Brightness & lock

Or, if present, from the battery icon in the panel.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I knew how to do this already.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way I can change these by setting presets. For example:

"Never Off"
Suspend/Critically Low/Lid Closed/Turn screen off after are all set to Never